# Module to Automatically Create URLs from Article Titles for Drupal 8

Tags: uri

I am wondering if there exists a module that would automatically create "nice" URLs using titles of posts in Drupal 8. I am aware of aliasing; however, if there is a lot of posting activity on the site,  it can become a substantial time sink.

**Example:** (something along these lines would suffice)

**Title of a post:**

> How to create neat URLs in Drupal 8

**corresponding URL:**

> www.example.com/how-to-create-neat-urls-drupal-8

Comment: You can use the Pathauto module for this: http://dgo.to/pathauto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module with [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token). Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Just to clarify, does Pathauto require Token or will I simply need both modules to set up what I would like?

Comment: Token is required - it is what will power the options when generating aliases.